# Difference Between Duplicating?

Tags: big-sur, file

is there a difference between "exactly duplicate" and "duplicate"?

File> Duplicate / Exactly Duplicate

Comment: In which application do you see this?

Comment: For example, if you mark a file on your Mac and then go to the storage space, the first thing it says is "Duplicate". However, as soon as you press "Option + Shift" it says "duplicate exactly". Now you have to enter your administrator password.

Comment: Darwin OS X, Please include all relevant information in the body of the question itself. As the question is current written it is not at all clear what is being referenced and probably why it was downvoted.

Comment: Excuse me. Will pay attention to this in the future

Comment: Instead of adding the answer to the question, can you please post an answer below and summarize the relevant part of that link (in english)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the answer the OP added to the question:

> When a directory or a file is duplicated, the (access) rights of the original file are usually not copied and the new file is owned by the copying user. However, if a Mac is used by several users or if network drives are involved, it can make sense not to make a file accessible to everyone.  To do this, right-click on a file, press <kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> and select "Duplicate exactly". This ensures that owner and access rights are copied as well.